# Max RAM capacity on modern cpus

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu, memory-hardware

I am wondering why modern consumer cpu usually has 128GB memory limit when server cpu supports terabytes. 128GB is really not that much.

Do they really can't handle more RAM? How wide is their address bus?

Is it possible to put more RAM if motherboard handles it?

-- Edit --

I think that my question is simple, but let me clarify it.

As we know theoretical limit of address space for 64bit is very large.
I know that currently no one supports it (both on software and hardware).
Windows x64 supports at least 2TiB, but it works with virtual memory so it doesn't have to be RAM only.
On the other hand [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Architectural_features) states that virtual and physical address space uses 48 bits which is 256TiB of RAM.

Looking at the numbers MMU is able to translate at least 2TiB from virtual to physical space so my question is: "Why Intel/AMD states in the spacification that processor supports only 128GB of RAM?"
Is it limited by design in hardware or artificialy to force people to buy more expensive cpus with larger limits?

Comment: a CPU definitely does *not* have that much memory... Maybe you meant hard disk (or SSD)?

Comment: Questions about consumer hardware are off-topic here.

Comment: See: [Fan out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fan-out)

Comment: Around 50,000 dollars will buy you a Dell computer or a Mac with 1.5TB of RAM. For storage, you can buy 60TB SSD drives, plug 10 of them into a USB hub, plug 10 of those into another 10 port USB hub, and plug probably four of those hubs into your $50,000 computer. Can’t see a reason why that wouldn’t work.

Comment: Where is it specified in Intel/AMD manuals that there is a limit of 128GB of RAM?

Comment: Max Memory size https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/134594/intel-core-i712700k-processor-25m-cache-up-to-5-00-ghz/specifications.html

Comment: They are designed this way to save costs - less memory controllers - also less testing - also price segmentation. If you want 2TiB of RAM, get a server CPU!

Comment: "128GB is really not that much": my first programs (which were not trivial) ran comfortably with 16K of RAM. What real life problem would truly require such an amount ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no fundamental reason. It's simply an engineering decision, an implementation detail. If you want 1TB of RAM, you buy a server system that can handle 1TB of RAM, not a desktop system that can only handle 32GB.

The limitation is more likely to be in the memory controllers which generate the electrical signals to talk to the memory chips, not in the memory management unit. More chips means more signals, more complex decoding, and also stronger drive current needed to make the signal reach all the chips. Servers often use "registered ECC" where each RAM stick has a "register" which acts as a signal booster.

The same memory management unit (or a very similar unit) is used on the 1TB systems and the 32GB systems - so the same software can run on both units